# Efficient, governor-aware string processing/validation in apex

Tags: apex, string

I need to make sure that a string only contains ASCII characters and not any other character (e.g., from another alphabet). I need to run this in real-time on hundreds of text fields so performance is very important. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: this is amenable to experimentation. what have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean "hundreds of text field", literally hundreds of fields or a field on hundreds of records? If the latter a validation rule using reggae would be the solution

Comment: I'm validating the data in ~5 custom objects and 10-20 fields on each for every one record validation. That would mean something like
records * 5 * 15 (on average).

Comment: I know I can compare the strings to a list of valid characters but wasn't sure if that's the best way to go as I know my list of valid characters are ASCII characters and it should be a common requirement.

Comment: SFDC regex (Pattern and Matcher) classes would be your friend here